# Boostrap Navigation menu dropdown not working

Tags: python, html, css, django

Im using bootstrap to develop a online web app. The navigation is not working, i tried a few things but no luck. I have bootstrap css files stored in my static directory.

***My Navbar Code is below***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{%load staticfiles%}
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Maps - Map</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/2-col-portfolio.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>


  <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'polls:home' %}">FestiMaps</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'polls:home' %}">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


<center>
<div class = "section">
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
</center>








<footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <center><p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Maps Creators 2019</p></center>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>


  </body>

</html>


<style class="cp-pen-styles">
body
{
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #27ae60;
}
```

I expect the navigation bar to work as expected by showing me a list of what is in it when I click onto the navbar.

Comment: What exactly is happening? More details around what is being rendered, any errors on the server side or client side are useful things. Saying it doesn't work is less so as that can be interpreted multiple ways.

Comment: Also look at your browser developer tools. Are there any errors in the javascript console? or page not found errors?

Comment: I get the following error in dev tools "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @TawhidAbdallah How are you linking those bootstrap files? can you add that to your question?

Comment: @Declan I have added how im linking them inside the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{%load staticfiles%}
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Maps - Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'polls:home' %}">FestiMaps</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'polls:home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>            
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<center>
<div class = "section">
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
</center>








<footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <center><p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Maps Creators 2019</p></center>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>


  </body>

</html>
```